# Org Mode and the `org-todo` function

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am trying to write a few keybindings.

`M-x describe-function org-todo` gives:

```
...

When called through ELisp, arg is also interpreted in the following way:
`none'             -> empty state
""(empty string)  -> switch to empty state
`done'             -> switch to DONE
`nextset'          -> switch to the next set of keywords
`previousset'      -> switch to the previous set of keywords
"WAITING"         -> switch to the specified keyword, but only if it
                     really is a member of `org-todo-keywords'.
```

However, I am trying to use the `'previousset` symbol as:

```
(org-todo 'previousset)
```

which does not work.  I know I am calling it validly because

```
(org-todo "TODO")
```

changes it to a TODO.

Where is `previousset` symbol defined? I can't find a definition anywhere.

**ANSWER:**   I worked out that `(org-todo 'left)` does what I want.  Note that the `left` symbol is not defined, so it sort of acts as a string instead of a variable, as CantrianBear describes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the comments to [following question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21132/how-does-org-agenda-todo-arg-work-what-does-the-argument-mean/21134#21134) pretty much answers your question.
`previousset` as well as `nextset` lead you to the next set of defined keywords. For that to work, `org-todo-keywords` needs to contain multiple keywords:

```
(setq org-todo-keywords '((sequence "TODO" "DONE") 
                          (sequence "TODO2" "DONE2")))
```

If you just want to cycle through your defined keywords in one sequence, simply type C-c C-t (org-todo).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and example `:)`.  I couldn't understand why these arguments contain the word "set".  Now I know.

Comment: `(org-todo 'left)` goes to the previous keyword in the sequence.  Thanks for mentioning that "symbols" don't have to be defined.